# Fires 'onChange' from Second Change

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, browser

I want onchange event fires only from the second change.

```
 Options
<select onchange="myFunc()">
    <option>--select--</option>
    <option>item1</option>
    <option>item2</option>
    <option>item3</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
function myFunc() {
    alert("option changed")
}
```

In above code, I want to call the function from ,when the option selected second time only. Already IE8 Fires 'onChange' for Every Second Change.
Any possibility is available for works on other browsers??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `counter` to save event count.

```
var counter = 0; // Initialize to zero

function myFunc() {
    if (counter++ > 0) { // Check if second click onwards
        alert("option changed");
        // Event handling code here
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/tvpdepke/)